# Insert custom UI icons into word document without providing icon

Tags: vba, user-interface, ms-word, user-controls, icons

Microsoft provided a Custom UI editor to edit Ribbon and create your own. You can also add symbols to that particular button added through UI editor. These symbols are integrate which means that they are in that file. As seen in image:
[image]

I am stuck in a situation where I need to Insert that particular custom UI icons into MS word document using a macro.

```
    Set newDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set mytable = _
     newDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, _
     NumColumns:=2)
    mytable.Rows.Height = 50
    mytable.Cell(1, 1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(1.3), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
    mytable.Cell(1, 2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(5.3), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
    mytable.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603917569
    mytable.Cell(1, 2).Range.InsertAfter "<Enter information content here>"
    mytable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Select
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture fileName:= _
    ActiveDocument.path & "\Bulb.png", LinkToFile:=False, _
    SaveWithDocument:=True 'Here I need something which will insert integrated bulb icon
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Selection.Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter
    mytable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Select
    Selection.Font.Color = wdColorGray35
    Selection.Font.Italic = wdToggle
    Selection.Font.ItalicBi = wdToggle
    Selection.Font.Size = 11
```

**Is there a way to insert that particular icon into MS word document?** so that it can work on any other computers without providing icon file.

My final result should be look like this:
[image]

Comment: Short answer - No.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt please explain it  I have to convince  a person who don't know about macros and he think that it is possible through VBA

Comment: I have already explained to you the only practical method that can be used - a template containing a Quick Part/Building Block. Otherwise you will need code that unzips the document, navigates the resulting folder structure, inserts the image into the document and rezips the document.